# iOS - How to draw a shaped line with CGContextRef

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can I draw a shaped line? For example a heart, diamond or star line with `CGContextRef`?

Heart line example:

[image]

Diamond line example:

[image]

Triangle line example:

[image]

Star line example:

[image]

This is what I currently have:

```
- (void)draw
{
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextAddPath(context, path);
    CGContextSetLineCap(context, kCGLineCapRound);
    CGContextSetLineWidth(context, self.lineWidth);
    CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, self.lineColor.CGColor);
    CGContextSetBlendMode(context, kCGBlendModeNormal);
    CGContextSetAlpha(context, self.lineAlpha);
    CGContextStrokePath(context);
}
```

The above code only draws a normal pen line.

Can I draw the shaped lines with an a .png image made from photoshop? Please guide me on how to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have create dummy app for you please look at idea how we can achieve custom line drawing.

Let me know if you need some more help.

https://github.com/tikamsingh/ShapeDrawing

Comment: Wow. Works great. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome @imstillalive